# Unable to run cmake with headers!

Tags: cmake

I am trying to follow the first step from this tutorial: [Tutorial STEP1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html)

I am having an issue with the third exercise there. We need to create a .h file in the build directory, but the .cxx "c++" file is in another directory. The tutorial says that we need to just include the .h file assuming it is in the same folder as the "cxx" file. But I get the following error!

[image: Error Message]

Can anyone suggest anything to fix this?

Comment: you most definitely should not create a .h in the build directory! That's *exactly* against the out-of-source build ideology behind CMake. I'm not finding where you read that from the tutorial. Could you point to *specifically* the steps you're doing?

Comment: ah I think you didn't read the "Start with TODO 1 and work through TODO 3." of "Step 1"; you tried to do TODO 8 (which is very advanced; not something people use daily), and then used the word "create" instead of "generate", and I guess that confused me?

Comment: So, if you, in contradiction to your statement in your question are already at STEP3, don't forget to use the hinted-at `target_include_directories` :)